# Can I make maven-assembly-plugin go faster?

Tags: performance, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a maven multi-module project.  The final goal wraps up all the libraries, etc., that we build in a tarball and RPM for distribution.  This goal uses the maven-assembly-plugin, and it takes *forever* -- usually a quarter to a half of our total build time.

I think we're already telling Maven to run multithreaded (though I'm not positive, and don't know how to check).  Is there any other optimization I can do to make unpacking / repacking go faster?  Is it just a matter of using a beefier machine?  Our project doesn't seem *that* big (end result is ~70-80 MB) but it takes well over a minute just for that one phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing memory by specifying MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx[some large value].  I managed to speed it up significantly, but it is still slower than tar.  If I have time I will get the sources and profile it.

Comment: I did bump my memory to 1GB, and I think it's going a *bit* faster -- this may just be bound by CPU speed on the build box, zipping and unzipping a whole lot of files...

Comment: For my benchmark, going to 2GB (8GB in system, 2GB+ free) in my case slightly slowed down the assembly: 34.2s originally, 35.5s with 2GB.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this happen when the maven reactor is *huge*, for a multi-module, multilevel project with enormous dependency hierarchy. If this is the your case, you might consider splitting your maven project to smaller ones, or suggest/ask for improvement for the maven assembly-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version of the Maven Assembly plugin. Newer versions are much faster than older ones.